# Unable to delete text from field XCUITest

Tags: swift, ios13, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I have a function that looks like this:

```
func clearText() {
        guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
            XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string value")
            return
        }

        let deleteString: String = stringValue.map { _ in XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue }.joined(separator: "")
        self.typeText(deleteString)
    }
```

This deletes text on currently focused/tapped field for all fields, except date of birth field.
I don't get any error, but it doesn't delete text.

This is what happens in debug mode:

```
    t =    48.41s Tap TextField
    t =    48.41s     Wait for com.xxx to idle
    t =    48.43s     Find the TextField
    t =    48.57s     Check for interrupting elements affecting "01.01.1988" TextField
    t =    48.60s     Synthesize event
    t =    48.68s     Wait for com.xxx to idle
    t =    52.26s Find the "01.01.1988" TextField
    t =    76.21s Type '' into "01.01.1988" TextField
    t =    76.21s     Wait for com.xxx to idle
    t =    76.24s     Find the "01.01.1988" TextField
    t =    76.42s     Check for interrupting elements affecting "01.01.1988" TextField
    t =    76.46s     Synthesize event
    t =    76.66s     Wait for com.xxx to idle
```

Screenshot of the app/simulator.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you select all first, or backspace over all the text?

Comment: @matt thanks for suggestion. In the end, I will just leave it as it is. It can't be deleted manually either by selecting all and deleting/cutting text, I think it's because it is a date picker field so only what is in the date picker can be set, but text can not be deleted.